# Downloading issue with safari

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, safari

While downloading any file from safari on Macbook Air, If downloading is paused due to any reason like internet access lost..etc, I am imposed to restart the downloading process rather than resuming.
is there any solution?

Comment: what is your Safari version, MBA, and OSX

Comment: Safari version 12.0(14606.1.36.1.9)

Answer (score 3):

It is sometimes possible to resume downloads in Safari. Click the download icon in the toolbar, and check the color of the "↻" icon. If the icon is gray, just click it to resume the download. However, if the icon is orange, do not click it, as Safari will delete the partially downloaded data and restart the download from scratch.

When Safari cannot resume a download, it is usually possible to resume it with curl instead. I do this so often, I actually made an Automator workflow to expedite the process.

https://github.com/Wowfunhappy/Automator-Quick-Actions/blob/master/Resume%20Download.workflow.zip?raw=true

1. Extract the zip file
2. Double click the .workflow and install it.

The next time a Safari download fails in the middle:

1. Go to the recent download list in Safari. If applicable, click the "x" to fully cancel the download, and then click the magnifying glass to reveal it in Finder. DO ***NOT*** click the orange retry ("↻") button; doing so will delete all partially downloaded data.
2. In Finder, right click on the partially downloaded file and select either `Resume Download` or `Services` → `Resume Download`.
3. Wait for the percentage in the terminal window to reach 100%. Note that this percentage does not include the part of the file that was downloaded previously, so it will always start at 0. If the download fails again, resume it again by focusing on the terminal window, hitting the up arrow key, and then the enter key.

Not all downloads can be resumed this way—some servers make it technically impossible—but in my experience it usually works.

Answer (score 1):

Hifsa, it is always best to indicate what versions of macOS you have and also what specific model of Mac you have when asking a question here. It is often necessary to have that information to provide a (potential) solution. Both are available under the Apple Menu by selecting "About this Mac."

That said if a download does not complete you can click on the download icon in the Safari Toolbar and get a list of recent downloads. If the download failed for whatever reason there will be a light gray circular icon to the right of the file name that you can click on to resume the download.

It will depend on why the download failed as to whether or not the download will resume or start over. I have seen both behaviors on Macs in a variety of macOS versions with little or no understanding of why some you can pick up where you left off and some require you to start over from scratch.